# Message in Ruby (Mac OS X)

Tags: ruby, macos

I get this error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:213: 
warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/Administrador/android-sdks in PATH, mode 040777 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bin/avd (LoadError)     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'  from bin/rec.rb:41:in `<main>'
```

and I think it is related to the ruby version installed in the MacBook Pro.

Can you help me, what I have to do? Reinstall something?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a directory called "android-sdks" in the home directory of user `Administrador`.  The directory has been added to your `PATH` and has permissions set such that other users could add executables there.  That makes it a security risk, and Ruby is refusing to let that happen.  Try removing public write and access from that directory.  If using the finder, right click (or ctrl-click) on the directory and select "Get Info".  At the bottom of the info window, change the privilege for "everyone" to "Read Only" or "No Access".  If you prefer to do it from the command-line, open Terminal.app, navigate to the parent folder, and type `chmod go-rwx android-sdks`.